# custom tableviewcell is nil

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, custom-cell

I have a table and I want to fill it with custom tableViewCells, in order to provide the user with information on orders. The problem is that the tableview shows the cells but does not fill them with the information I need. When I inserted breakpoints, I found out that the cells are nill, not matter what I do. this is my cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    OrderOverViewCell *cell = (OrderOverViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: @"orderOverviewCell"];

    OrderClass *orderClass = nil;
    if (filteredArray == nil) {
        if (sortedArray.count >0) {
        orderClass = sortedArray[indexPath.row];
        }
    }
    else if (filteredArray != nil) {
        orderClass = filteredArray[indexPath.row];
    }

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"];
    NSString *orderDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:orderClass.orderDate];

    cell.orderTitle.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@ %@",orderClass.companyName,@",", orderDate];
    cell.orderDetail.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@ %@.", @"order nummer:",orderClass.orderNumber, @"betaling:", orderClass.orderPaymentType];


    if ([orderClass.orderDelivery isEqualToString:@"Bezorgen"]) {
        cell.orderDelivery.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Levering: Bezorgen op %@, %@, %@", orderClass.orderAdress, orderClass.orderAdressZip, orderClass.orderCity];
    }

    if ([orderClass.orderDelivery isEqualToString:@"Afhalen"]) {
        cell.orderDelivery.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Levering: Afhalen op ingestelde datum en tijd."];
    }

    cell.orderIndication.image = nil;
    if ([orderClass.preparing isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
        if ([orderClass.ready isEqualToString:@"1"] ){
            if ([orderClass.delivered isEqualToString:@"1"]){
                cell.orderIndication.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"order_3.png"];
            }
            else {
                cell.orderIndication.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"order_2.png"];
            }
        }
        else {
            cell.orderIndication.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"order_1.png"];
        }
    }
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"orderCellBG.png"]];

    return cell;
}
```

Does anybody have an idea what i'm doing wrong? any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Are you defining the custom cell view inside a Storyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing it to this solved it:

```
OrderOverViewCell *cell = (OrderOverViewCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: @"orderOverviewCell"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in viewDidLoad to indicate the cell to use:

```
UINib *const cell = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"nibName" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[_tableView registerNib:cell forCellReuseIdentifier:@"orderOverviewCell"];
```

Comment: I'm afraid that's not working because I use storyboards, thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

If you're defining your custom cell as a `Prototype Cell` inside a `Storyboard`, make sure you have assigned the proper identifier (`orderOverviewCell`)

[image]

According to [Apple developer docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html)

> Because the prototype cell is defined in a storyboard, the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: method always returns a valid cell. You don’t need to check the return value against nil and create a cell manually.

Comment: do you have an idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Well, a typo in your cell Identifier was my best shot :) But I'm pretty sure you shouldn't need to manually create your cell. Let me look if I'm missing something else.

Comment: I have other classes in which this process works perfectly. some little detail must be wrong here but i can't figure out what. thanks in advance for your effort

Comment: Mmh in these cases, sometimes it's worthy to restart from scratch. Anyway, you could double check that you have your tableview, delegate and datasource correctly linked to the right controller. I'd also check that you haven't accidentally added spaces to the end of the cell identifier in the storyboard, and that your prototype cell Custom class is correctly set in Identity Inspector. If nothing of these work, you'll probably save time repeating the process from zero :(

Comment: well, I just started changing some variables and rewrote some lines of code. It works again!

Comment: Glad you solved it :) By the way, if you found useful any answer, please, consider upvoting/checking right answer, it may be helpful for other users too.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to check! If you are using Storyboards and your cell is a prototype cell which is contained inside a UITableView instead of a separate Nib file then make sure the unique identifier is correct.

The case as well as spelling matters so make sure you have named the "orderOverviewCell" correctly in the code as well as in the storyboard when you click on the cell.

```
OrderOverViewCell *cell = (OrderOverViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: @"orderOverviewCell"];
```

The above code will instantiate the cell and return a valid cell so you don't need to check for nil or anything. I am also assuming that you are using UITableViewController and not a ViewController with a UITableView as an outlet.